# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open C:\myangularproject\src\node_modules\nlcst-pattern-match\lib\index.js

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

This just started!

I have an angular 5 project that "was" working and then, I was fixing my SCSS paths and installed Python 37 and WHAMO, all this happens.

What I did:

1) Deleted Package-Lock.json
2) Deleted the node-modules folder
3) did a fresh npm install
4) Deleted the nclst-pattern-match folder
5) Ran ng serve and the problem still shows
6) Installed npm nclst-pattern-match and the problem still shows

Anyone with thoughts on this would help me considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error clearly states that it cannot find the nclst folder. Why did you delete it after the npm install? Re run npm install and dont delete that folder.

And after installing you Need to stop angular and re run it.

Comment: I have, several times, it's physically there. I've deleted the node-modules folder, re-ran npm install and when I start the server: ng serve, the error still occurs. Weird.  I may have to re-clone a fresh copy of the master branch. It's just something I cannot resolve Roberto!

Comment: Wait, I hit CTRL-C and stop the server... I need to do that "THEN" re-type ng serve.... correct?

Comment: Roberto, I stopped Angular, did another npm install, did an ng serve and still get this:

$ ng serve --env=dev165
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\myangularproject\src\node_modules\nlcst-pattern-match\lib\index.js'

I'm dumbfounded.

Comment: After I downloaded a fresh branch, it worked. Then I added the nlcst-pattern-match and nlcst-parse-english with no errors!

Comment: Im glad is working. Make sure that package is listed in the package.json dependencies. If not. Add it with —save flag. (Thats two dashses)